# Error in accessing google reader's Endpoints API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, google-reader

I am trying to implement google reader in iPhone APP and so far I have successfully received the **sid** and **auth**. The problem arises when I try to call the Endpoints API with **GET**.. Here's the code:

```
 ASIHTTPRequest *request = [self requestForAPIEndpoint:@"https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/list?output=json"];
 [request setDelegate:self];
 [request startAsynchronous];

- (ASIHTTPRequest *) requestForAPIEndpoint: (NSString *) apiEndpoint
{
 ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: apiEndpoint]];
[request addRequestHeader: @"User-Agent" value: @"YourClient"];
 [request addRequestHeader: @"Cookie" value: signature];
 NSLog(@"Sig = %@",signature);
 [request addRequestHeader: @"Authorization" value: autho];
 return request.
}
```

The autho and signature are correctly set. However every-time I get callback in - **(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request** method. What is that I am doing wrong?? Do I need to register some where to access the API and set the user-agent to that name??

I modified the **requestForAPIEndpoint** method as follows then also I have the same problem.

```
- (ASIHTTPRequest *) requestForAPIEndpoint: (NSString *) apiEndpoint
{

NSDictionary *properties = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[properties setValue:signature forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
[properties setValue:@"SID" forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
[properties setValue:@".google.com" forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];
[properties setValue:@"1600000000" forKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires];
[properties setValue:@"/" forKey:NSHTTPCookiePath];
NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [[[NSHTTPCookie alloc] initWithProperties:properties] autorelease];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: apiEndpoint]];
[request setUseCookiePersistence:NO];
[request setRequestCookies:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:cookie]];

[request addRequestHeader: @"User-Agent" value: @"YourClient"];
[request addRequestHeader: @"Authorization" value: autho];
 return request;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to provide the SID cookie if you are using ClientLogin (via the `Authorization` header). See http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki/Authentication for the supported authentication schemes.

Additionally, the `Authorization` header should be formatted as `GoogleLogin auth=<auth token>` where `<auth token>` is the `Auth` value from the ClientLogin response.

Comment: After removing the SID cookie also, there is no change. The response fails again.

Comment: What is the value of the `autho` variable in your code? The expected format is `GoogleLogin auth=<auth value>` where `<auth value>` is what you got back from the ClientLogin.

Comment: Autho was only the auth id.. When I changed it to GoogleLogin auth=<auth id> it worked like charm.. Thanx a lot. If you can edit and put this in answer, I will select this as accepted.